# I need to know which of 4 keys are pressed in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a game in batch, and I need to know which keys are pressed.

```
@echo off 

:move
choice /c wasd /n
if errorlevel 1 goto w
if errorlevel 2 goto a
if errorlevel 3 goto s
if errorlevel 4 goto d

:w
echo w
goto move

:a
echo a
goto move

:s
echo s
goto move

:d
echo d
goto move
```

I came up with this code after looking at some other questions on here, but it just outputs "w". I would like to try to keep this in one window.

Comment: `if errorlevel 1` means if it is 1 or greater. reverse de logic from greater to lower or use `if %errorlevel% equ 1` again, it’s best practice reverse the logic

Comment: you may also `goto :move_%errorlevel%` and remame labels as `:move_1 ... :move_4`

Comment: ... and because a label ignores anything after a space, make your code more readable by `:move_1 w North`

Comment: The use of ERRORLEVEL with the `choice` command utility, is clearly shown in the usage information for that command. Open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and pay particular attention to the `NOTE`, where it should tell you how it works and explain that `When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list them in decreasing order`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already been told in the comment, `errorlevel 1` means if `errorlevel` is 1 or higher, therefore you need to reverse the order. What really happens is that it tests `errorlevel` with the number you provide, so consider you pressed `a` meaning `errorlevel` is set to `2`. It will test if `2` is greater than or equal to 4, which it is not, then it moves to the next, until it reaches the point where it sees that errorlevel is 2 or higher, and it then follows the `goto` command:

```
if errorlevel 4 goto d
if errorlevel 3 goto s
if errorlevel 2 goto a
if errorlevel 1 goto w
```

You could however simply skip the entire `if` set and use `goto %errorlevel%` for instance:

```
@echo off 
:move
choice /c wasd /n
goto move_%errorlevel%

:move_1
echo w & goto :move
:move_2
echo a & goto :move
:move_3
echo s & goto :move
:move_4
echo d & goto :move
```

Obviously you want to do other things in the labels, but if you really only wanted to see which keys were pressed, or run single commands you could do:

```
@echo off
set "_1=w" & set "_2=a" & set "_3=s" & set "_4=d"
:move
choice /c wasd /n
call echo %%_%errorlevel%%%
```